# AOP Advice not getting executed

Tags: spring, gradle, aspectj

I am using AspectJ AOP with spring. I am NOT USING spring AOP but AspectJ AOP with spring.

I am using load time weaving. My advices are not getting executed. Any leads would greatly help.

```
@Aspect
public class ProfilingAspect {

    @Around("methodsToBeProfiled()")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Hello #################");
        return pjp.proceed();
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.core.search.domain.AIESearchDomainService.doSearch())")
    public void methodsToBeProfiled() {
    }
}
```

Following is the method on which I am trying to run the advice.

```
package com.core.search.domain;


public class AIESearchDomainService {

    public SearchResponse doSearch() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have enabled load time weaving using the the below annotation.

```
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
```

I have also specified the java agent for enabling the load time weaver as below.

```
-javaagent:"pathTo/spring-instrument-5.3.25.jar"
```

I have also created aop.xml and kept it in /resources/META-INF folder.

```
<aspectj>

    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="com.core.search.domain.*"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="package.for.ProfilingAspect"/>
    </aspects>

</aspectj>
```

There are no errors in the code but my advice is not getting executed. Please help. I believe weaving is happening because I am able to see the following log.

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
```

Comment: Are your target classes in subpackages of `com.core.search.domain` rather than directly inside that package? Then you should use the double-dot notation `..*` instead of `.*` in order to include them, e.g. `com.core.search.domain..*`. This is a common mistake. Let me know if it helps, then I can convert this message into an answer which you then can accept in order to close the question.

Comment: Yes, my classes are directly present under the domain package, but thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, AOP works with the following aop.xml file.

```
<aspectj>

    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include name="package.for.ProfilingAspect"/>
        <include within="com.core.search.domain.*"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="package.for.ProfilingAspect"/>
    </aspects>

</aspectj>
```

Just including the Aspect class in weaver tag made it work, I am yet to understand how.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Sorry, this answer cannot be correct. It is perfectly fine to have the native AspectJ aspect in another package and not mention it as a weaving target. It would not even make sense to do so, as aspects do not weave themselves under normal circumstances. Whatever made your configuration work, it was not what you describe here. I suggest to find out what really fixed the proble and then edit the answer. If you cannot find out, please delete the answer, becaus it is just plain wrong.

Comment: You can use `<weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">` in order to see what gets woven by your _aop.xml_ configuration and generally see some more weaver output.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to enable aspectjWeaving param

```
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving=ENABLED)
```

Comment: This is not possible. The default value of the attribute is AUTODETECT which automatically enabled the weaving if aop.xml file is present.

  /**
   * Switches on AspectJ load-time weaving if a "META-INF/aop.xml" resource
   * is present in the classpath. If there is no such resource, then AspectJ
   * load-time weaving will be switched off.
   */
  AUTODETECT;

Comment: did you already check if weaving process actually works. You can use this <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo -debug">

Comment: Yeah, I don't see the class on which I want to run my advice getting weaved. Can you please suggest why could this be happening

Comment: Your pointcut expression looks wrong. it should be "com.core.search.domain. AIESearchDomainService.doSearch()"

Comment: Weaving is getting invoked but in logs I am only seeing the classes that are not getting weaved. example "debut not weaving ........"

Comment: have updated the post. Point cut is right.

Comment: try simplifying your pointcut like this @Pointcut("within(com.core.search.domain.AIESearchDomainService)"). If this doesn't work that means your weaving is not working correctly